# MySQL Computed Column Based on Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql

My apologies if this question has already been answered on here. It might be the case that I have worded this poorly in my searches so far.

Is it possible to create a computed column that sums previous rows with a matching column?

For example, if I have a table called "sales", I want to create a column that sums the previous number of sales with a matching customer_id?

```
id | customer_id | previous_customer_sale_qty
---------------------------------------------
1  | 1           | 0
2  | 2           | 0
3  | 1           | 1
```

Comment: See the [SUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function

Comment: I'm looking more for something closer to a conditional auto-increment. I'm familiar with using SUM() but that's not necessarily what I'm looking for. If I pull a list of records and iterate through that list, I want to see for sale#1 that the customer has had no previous sales... and when I see sale#3, I would see they have had 1 previous sale.

Comment: So is `previous_customer_sale_qty` an existing column that's already being populated? Or is that the column you want to know how to populate?

Comment: It's a column I want to create. It doesn't exist and if possible I would like MySQL to handle the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(previous_customer_sale_qty) AS total, *
FROM sales
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Comment: This gives me the total sales. If I did a query that pulled sale#1, I want the value to be 0, even if the customer actually has 2 sales in his history.